# Make clangd to parse whole directories

Tags: c++, vscode-extensions, clangd

I'm using the clangd extension to analysis c/c++ base project in VS code , and this project use many open source projects ,and use the Atom.mk to determine how to build the project.
here come the problems:
cause the clangd only parse 3 paths relative to the opened cpp file , so some symbols can't be found while I use the "Goto definition" function. cause this definition is completed by other source code .
how can I setup the clangd ,make it parse the whole files in directory like C++ intellisense ?

PS: the c++ intellisense is slow in my linux environment, so I discard it. And I google the results ,just told me to use the compile_command.json tell the clang how to build the projects, how is that possible to generate all compile_command.json in all sub_directorys ?

Answer (score 0):

As you found, getting clangd to index all the source files in a project is accomplished by having a `compile_commands.json` file with an entry for each source file in the project.

The `compile_commands.json` file is usually generated at build time. The exact mechanism will vary depending on your project's build system (see https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#project-setup for some examples), but a common way is to use [Bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) to wrap your build command, e.g. if your build command is `make`, you would run `bear -- make` and `bear` will record the compiler commands invoked during the build and generate the `compile_commands.json` based on them.

Comment: thanks reply. Cause my project is a embeded software , the whole project is assemble by a 3rd building system. And I try to pass the commands to the Bear , the first time I got the empty compile_commands.json file ,then I clean the project , Now I'm waiting for the result .

Comment: I got the result , and the compile_command.json was generated successfully , But it seems that the cland server still can't locate some symbols , so the problems still back to how to parsing whole folders like gtags/c++ intellisense by clangd?

Comment: @lianzisong for a cross-compilation setup, you probably need to use `--query-driver`, please see https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#cant-find-standard-library-headers-map-stdioh-etc (particularly the last paragraph), and also `clangd --help` for more details about the `--query-driver` option